# Use jupyter notebook with flask and websockets

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, websocket, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a data science project with **realtime streaming data**. The data is received using a Flask app running websockets.

I have to use this realtime data in my model and perform some actions based on this data. This is a long running project. I have the following requirements:

- Setup a long **running process ML project**, preferably on a remote server or Google Colab. It should be independent of my local machine.
- Connect it to incoming streaming data. The **data is streamed using Flask**, Nodejs or PHP app.
- **Visualise** realtime data using graphs using my browser.
- Perform **Actions based on data** driven triggers from the notebook.
- **Save the output** from the actions to a remote postgres database.

For analogy, consider an example of Realtime Stocks analysis and trading. The stock prices vary every second. Appropriate buy/sell decisions are taken based on ML models crunching the data.

**I am open for all suggestions**, including replacing Jupyter notebook with a more robust technology for production deployment.

The Flask code is as follows:

```
# Initialise
kws = Ticker("your_api_key", "your_access_token")

def on_ticks(ws, ticks):
    # Callback to receive ticks.
    logging.debug("Ticks: {}".format(ticks))

def on_connect(ws, response):
    # Callback on successful connect.
    # Subscribe to a list of instrument_tokens.
    ws.subscribe([12345])

def on_close(ws, code, reason):
    # On connection close stop the main loop
    # Reconnection will not happen after executing `ws.stop()`
    ws.stop()

# Assign the callbacks.
kws.on_ticks = on_ticks
kws.on_connect = on_connect
kws.on_close = on_close

# Infinite loop on the main thread. Nothing after this will run.
# You have to use the pre-defined callbacks to manage subscriptions.
kws.connect()
```

My notebook code is as follows:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

def long_running_process(dataframe):
    # continuously populate data in the dataframe from the streaming data.
    # Keep triggering decisions based on incoming data.
```

---

**PS 1**

I am reading some articles for ML projects deployment like
https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-for-streaming-data-with-creme-dacf5fb469df
But they are quite elaborate for my requirement. I need a simpler deployment strategy for my use case.